# Attempting to launch a python program using a .cmd file on windows 10

Tags: python, cmd, windows-10

I recently created a small python program that I distributed to a few friends. In order to make it more easy for them to launch the program, I used files named maclaunch.command and winlaunch.cmd files for mac and windows respectively so they could just double click the file in order to launch the program.

The program works fine on my computer (mac), and I tested it on a windows laptop we had lying around (windows 8) and it worked fine there as well. However, after I distributed it to a few friends and having them install Python 3 (the version of python that I am using) we appear to be experiencing an error in windows 10 where the winlaunch.cmd file doesn't launch the program, instead flashing the command line app for just a second. It is supposed to launch the command line, but it should remain open long enough for people to read it. The program runs fine when I have them use IDLE to open and run it.

Here is the code for winlaunch.cmd (the one for windows):

```
py -3 source.py
```

Any one have some insight into how to fix this?

Comment: The order of execution here is cmd.exe -> conhost.exe -> py.exe -> python.exe. The console window is conhost. If no client process is attached to it, conhost simply quits, and the console window is destroyed. You need to have cmd.exe spawn a new instance of itself that will keep running interactively after py.exe exits. For that run `cmd /k py -3 source.py`.

Comment: Or add a `pause` command on the next line after `py -3 source.py`. That makes the instance of cmd that's executing the .cmd file wait until the user presses a key. Then cmd exits, and the console is destroyed.

Comment: I don't use python very often but you should maybe try with `python` instead of `py`. I have python 2.7.9 on Windows 10 and have no `py`, only `python`. Checking if they allowed the python installer to add python to the path could also help. But as @eryksun proposed, add a `pause` under your python command. You will then see what gets printed

Comment: Open a cmd window in the folder where "winlaunch.cmd" is located and run it in the commandline, the screen won't close and we'll be able to see the error your experiencing that causes the window to exit immediately. Or just run it like "cmd /k <path of winlaunch.cmd>" and let us know what you see.